# appropriate data structure, in time effiency and less storage concern?

Tags: java, data-structures

I will probably have keyword,value pair shown at below in my code. Keyword will be unique words, and value will likely be hash table. For this configurarion, what should be appropriate data structure, in time effiency and less storage concern ?

```
keyword(String)      value(HashMap<int, object of (String, float, ...)>)

stat    ----->    hash table 1
                  hash table 2
                  hash table 3
goog    ----->    hash table 
...
yand    ----->    hash table 1
                  hash table 2
```

Comment: `HashMap<String, List<HashTable>>`??. BTW (unless you meant your own implementation of hash table) HashTable is as good as deprecated. use ConcurrentHashMap instead.

Comment: What are those hash tables? My guess is that the list of hash tables should be encapsulated into a class.

Comment: And what is `HashMap<int, String, float, object>`supposed to mean? A Map associates a key with one value, not 3. And it dan't contain primitive types. I think you should focus on proper OO design and understand basics before caring about time efficiency and storage.

Answer (score 0):

For key,value pair you can use Map from collection.
Map allows you to store data in the form of key and value.

You can use following code segment for your reference:

```
class KeyValueOperation
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Map<String, ArrayList<Hashtable>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Hashtable>>();
    ArrayList<Hashtable> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<Hashtable>();
    Hashtable ht1=new Hashtable();
    Hashtable ht2=new Hashtable();
    Hashtable ht3=new Hashtable();
    arraylist1.add(ht1);
    arraylist1.add(ht2);
    arraylist1.add(ht3);

    ArrayList<Hashtable> arraylist2 = new ArrayList<Hashtable>();        
    Hashtable ht4=new Hashtable();
    Hashtable ht5=new Hashtable();
    Hashtable ht6=new Hashtable();
    arraylist2.add(ht4);
    arraylist2.add(ht5);
    arraylist2.add(ht6);

    map.put("state",arraylist1);
    map.put("goog",arraylist2);        

}
}
```